# SimpleCov to include engine codes at coverage report - Rails testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, simplecov

I am using SimpleCov as a coverage tool in my rails app. 
At this app, the code is divided to engines and i am including the engines to my app according to some inputs.

The problem with simplcov it generates the coverage report for the code inside the app only and it ignores the code at the engines. So does anyone has an solution for that?

Comment: Why don't you add simple cov to the engine for your tests on the engine in isolation?

Comment: Would you please clarify more?

Comment: You develop the engines separately right?  Add simple cov to each engine individually.

Comment: @SalemMohammed I am facing same issue. I am keen to know, any solution you found for this?

Answer (score 0):

you have to load every class before run code coverage. make `config.eager_load = true` in your rails environment file.